# How to apply a clip rect to a group or something similar?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a Phaser.group containing 6 images, the group has a height of 600px but I want only the first 3 images look with a height approximately 300px, for slot type effect on the images.

I have tried different options with .crop with mask, but I find the best solution.

How I can make a clipRect?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found a solution, I have problems with the positions of the Rectangle, here you have:

```
var maskGraphics = this.game.add.graphics(0,0);
maskGraphics.beginFill(200, 100, 0 , 0);
maskGraphics.drawRect(x , y, width,height); 
maskGraphics.endFill();

this.mask = maskGraphics
```

You must create an image and give it a alpha 0, assigning the size you want it to have the visible.

Add that image as a mask to the object you want, in my case it is a group but can be another image or other objets.

Working correctly with phaser v2.0.6

Comment: Yes the mask property is the way to do this. Remember the coordinates for the mask are in screen space, not local to the Sprite they are masking. Also you don't have to give it an alpha value for `beginFill`. The colour doesn't matter either, I tend to just use white, but any colour will do. You also don't need the call to `endFill` either, although I can understand why it feels "cleaner" to include it :) But the masking code ignores it.

Comment: Thank you very much @PhotonStorm, I refactored this. It has been confusing the use of masks, especially the positioning but congratulations on this awesome framework  

Final code:  

    var maskGraphics = this.game.add.graphics(0,0);
    maskGraphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
    maskGraphics.drawRect(x,y,width,height); 
    this.mask = maskGraphics;

Comment: Looks good to me :) Remember you can change `mask.x` (or `y` or any other property) and it will update the mask in real time without needing to re-apply it to the Sprite.